# Creating a New Marker in native-react-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

How can we create a new marker on a `react-native-maps` map by clicking on a draggable marker? This new marker will be created at the same location where the initial draggable marker was when the click happened.'

I can get the coordinates for the location of the new marker from `e.nativeEvent.coordinate`, but how can we create this new marker?

```
createMarker(e) {       
    console.log(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)  # here's the lng/lat for new marker
}

render() {
    <MapView
        ref='map'
        initialRegion={{
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        }}
    >

        <MapView.Marker 
            coordinate={{latitude: LATITUDE, longitude: LONGITUDE}}
            onPress={(e) => this.setPickupLocation(e)}
            draggable
        ></MapView.Marker>

    </MapView>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with rendering an array of markers then setState with a new array of markers that includes the new item.

In the case from below I'm setting a new one just near, and a bit above so it can be seen.

```
render() {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>MySupaFancyMap</Text>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                region={this.state.region}
                onRegionChangeComplete={this._onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this)}
            >
                {this.state.markers.map( (marker, index) => (
                    <MapView.Marker key={index}
                        coordinate={marker.latlng}
                        title={marker.title}
                        onPress={this._createMarker.bind(this, marker)}
                    />

                ))}
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
}
_createMarker (markerInfo) {
    newMarker = {
        latlng: {
            latitude: markerInfo.latlng.latitude+0.01,
            longitude: markerInfo.latlng.longitude+0.01
        }
    }

    markers = this.state.markers.concat([newMarker]);
    this.setState({markers});
}
```